# Inserting the duration between two times..in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am inserting two time values in the mysql database columns TIME1 and TIME2 respectively and at the same time i also want the duration between the two times to be calculated and be inserted into a DURATION named column..I tried some sub queries but being weak with database coding i am not able to do this..Also  Queries are being written in the java classes not in sql command line..Values are supposed to be entered in the same database..

```
Insert into meeting_hall_booking_master(booking_duration)
select TIMEDIFF(booking_to_time,booking_from_time) from meeting_hall_booking_master;
```

This query inserts a new row with the booking duration calulated with the help of the values of TIME1 and TIME2 of its previous row.

Comment: I removed the java tag as your actual question seems to be purely about sql/mysql

Comment: no problem..i thought i would be helpful for other java programmers as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use update statement it will solve your problem

```
update meeting_hall_booking_master 
set booking_duration = TIMEDIFF(booking_to_time,booking_from_time);
```

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel : Did u try the above query ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you actually need an `update` statement now.

```
update meeting_hall_booking_master
 set booking_duration = TIMEDIFF( booking_to_time, booking_from_time )
```

Instead of updating on a later stage, you can set the duration value in the `insert` statement.

```
insert into 
 meeting_hall_booking_master( booking_to_time, booking_from_time, booking_duration )
 values ( @booking_to_time,
          @booking_from_time,
          timediff( @booking_to_time, @booking_from_time )
        )
```